# CMS for more than 600 Content rich Websites

Tags: web, content-management-system, content-management, ecm, wcm

I've got a little history in CMS technology and I wonder if anyone could recommend a CMS-System (esp. WCM) for large content rich websites. Consider a hierarchical tree structure of sites with e.g. 4-5 levels, where you have about 10 to 15 trees of sites.
e.g.:

1. Organisation 1-n
   1.1 Suborg 1-n
   1.2 Special-Microsite 1-n

You should further be able to share content & navigation within sites (trees) an attach own site-specific navigation and content to shared navigation - wich only appears in the site scope but not globally.

When you could say about a system it rocks even with 500+ sites and complex permission landscape, please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Alfresco](http://www.alfresco.com) is an open source ECM with Web Content Management .  It was started in 2005 by the former founder of Documentum and engineering team of former Documentum developers, and has been built by engineers with many years of experience from Interwoven, Vignette, and other ECM players.   It's a modern architecture, and is runtime-agnostic, so you can have .NET sites managed right next with Java Sites, PHP sites, etc.

Used by lots of large and medium sized enterprises all over the world (check customers list).

Comment: +1 Alfresco WCM is used by some news companies to maintain their many websites

Answer (score 2):

Use EMC Documentum.. Its not a open source WCM application, but its robust and really good for large systems. I have worked on it for complex permissions and large web sites.

Comment: Do you know of any Internet Site using ECM at that scale?

Answer (score 0):

If you are already using Oracle for [anything]. Then I would recommend looking at Oracle UCM 11g. The 11g version was released recently and boasts some impressive stats, capabilities.

http://www.oracle.com/technetwork/middleware/content-management/overview/index.html